# Create a Householder matrix in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have difficulties to create a [Householder matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation#Householder_matrix).

```
  M = \left(
    \begin{array}{c | c c c c}
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
      0 &  \\
      0 & H_{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4} \\
      0 &  \\
      0 &  \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use nicematrix package.

Comment: Thanks, I never used

Comment: @Gianni Spear What does the final outcome  have to look like ? or is it about the zeros placement on the top line ?

Comment: Hey. The final outcome  is a matrix with Hu in R^{4 x 4} centered and the first row of zeros in order (i.e., with equal spaces)

Comment: @Sebastiano it'd be great to see an answer using the `nicematrix` package, if you have time :)

Comment: @cmhughes In the meantime HAPPY NEW YEAR and you know that I am a scarce/poor user in TeX.SE :-):-). Just I wanted to try yesterday, but I think that the code is long. Generally I give also the other users fast and simple answer: look with my sincerity my profile. However thank you very much for your appreciate. Surely there is a block in the matrix as from documentation.

Comment: @cmhughes Done! I have found the inspiration ahahah. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
 M = \left(
    \begin{array}{c | c c c c}
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
      0 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{$H_{u}\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$}} \\
      0 & \\
      0 & \\
      0 & \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Nest `matrix` inside `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\[
M=\left(
  \begin{array}{c | c}
  1 & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\
  \hline
  \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} &
  H_u\in\RR^{4\times 4}
  \end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

$M=\begin{pNiceArray}{c|cccc}[margin]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
\hline
0 &   &  &  &\\
0 &   \Block[l]{3-3}<\large>{H_{u}\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4}}&  &  &\\
0 &  &  &   &\\
0 &  &  &   & 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done :) +1 from me

Comment: +1: Same from me

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you very much and my sincere best regards.